# Would it be legal for an American to hack Russian military infrastructure to aid Ukraine?

Tags: united-states, military, laws-of-war, ukraine, computer

I am an American citizen located in the US. Suppose I wanted to hack Russian military infrastructure and disable it in order to aid Ukraine. Would this be legal?

Comment: I don't think you'll find much criminal or political resistance in the US towards your actions. However, should you step into a Russian-allied state, you may find yourself in a bit of a pickle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's illegal.

[18 USC 1030](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1030), the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act, makes it illegal to, for instance, "intentionally access a protected computer without authorization, and as a result of such conduct, cause damage and loss."  A "protected computer" is defined to include any computer "which is used in or affecting interstate or foreign commerce or communication".  This effectively includes every computer in the world that's connected to the Internet (see [*US v. Trotter*](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-8th-circuit/1072284.html), 478 F.3d 918 (8th Cir. 2007).

To the best of my knowledge, Congress has not added any exceptions for Russia or any other specific country.

---

It's also likely to be forbidden by the laws of your state.  You did not specify a state, but taking Colorado as an example, the following are crimes under [C.R.S. 18-5.5-102](https://advance.lexis.com/api/document/collection/statutes-legislation/id/65S8-0X23-GXF6-84JX-00008-00?cite=C.R.S.%2018-5.5-102&context=1000516):

> (a) Accesses a computer, computer network, or computer system or any part thereof without authorization; exceeds authorized access to a computer, computer network, or computer system or any part thereof; or uses a computer, computer network, or computer system or any part thereof without authorization or in excess of authorized access; or
> [...]
>
> (e) Without authorization or in excess of authorized access alters, damages, interrupts, or causes the interruption or impairment of the proper functioning of, or causes any damage to, any computer, computer network, computer system, computer software, program, application, documentation, or data contained in such computer, computer network, or computer system or any part thereof; or
>
> (f) Causes the transmission of a computer program, software, information, code, data, or command by means of a computer, computer network, or computer system or any part thereof with the intent to cause damage to or to cause the interruption or impairment of the proper functioning of or that actually causes damage to or the interruption or impairment of the proper functioning of any computer, computer network, computer system, or part thereof [...]

Note that this applies to *any* target computer, and the prosecution would not have to prove that the computer was used in, or affected, interstate or foreign commerce or communication.

Other states most likely have similar laws.

Comment: The statute only covers computers outside the United States if they are "used in a manner that affects interstate or foreign commerce or communication of the United States."  Russian military infrastructure would not necessarily meet this definition.

Comment: @phoog: If the target computer is accessible from the United States, I think the spirit of *Trotter* would argue that it therefore affects the foreign communication of the United States.  If it's not, then I don't know how someone "located in the US" (as posited in the question) is going to hack it.

Comment: _Trotter_ seems to turn on the fact that the computers _were used_ in interstate commerce.  That is the case because they "were used to communicate with other computers outside the State of Missouri."  A foreign computer that is not used to communicate with the United States would not meet this test, at least arguably.  There is enough to differentiate this case from _Trotter_ that its applicability is not clear.

Comment: @phoog: I agree it's not 100% clear and I haven't found a case more directly on point.  That said, *Trotter* suggests that in general, the definition will be applied very broadly.  In particular, it could be argued that the defendant hacking the computer was, itself, an instance of the computer communicating with the United States.

Comment: @phoog: Just in case that argument does not fly, such hacking is also likely to be in violation of state law, which does not need to be limited to interstate or foreign commerce or communications.  I added a citation of Colorado's law.

Comment: Ok, I've removed my downvote.  I'm skeptical of the argument that the hacking itself implicating the computer in interstate commerce, but I'm sure it would be advanced and I suppose it might succeed.  I'm sure the state law is applicable, except I wonder what exceptions might exist in the context of war.  Surely laws criminalizing the destruction of property would not be enforced against someone who destroyed some property of an invading force.  Is there a formal legal principle involved?  If so, under what conditions could it apply to the hacking considered here.

Comment: @phoog: That's an interesting question and could be worth a separate post.  It's not relevant to  this question as the United States is not at war with Russia.

Comment: @NateEldredge You say that hacking foreign computer would be a crime under state law. The US Constitution gives the power to regulate interstate and foreign commerce & communication to the Federal government, not the states. Thus Colorado has no authority over hacking computers in other states, or outside the US. This is why Colorado's law do not mention interstate or foreign commerce and communication.

Comment: @phoog I understand your scepticism, but Nate is right about which computers are count as "protected" under §1030(e)(2)(B). As Justice Barrett said in Van Buren (2021), "§1030(e)(2)(B)...applies...to...all computers that connect to the Internet." Similarly, the US Attorney's Manual on "Prosecuting Computer Crime," (p. 4) says that to show a computer is covered by §1030(e)(2)(B), "it is enough that the computer is connected to the Internet..."

Comment: @phoog As you may know, these sorts of tenuous connections are common in cases involving the interstate commerce power.  For example, in Raich (2004), the Court held that a CA medical marijuana patient, who grew just enough for her own use, "affected" interstate commerce enough to justify federal regulation.

Comment: @phoog Art. I, § 8 gives Congress the power to "grant Letters of Marque and Reprisal..." These letters basically give private citizens a license to go to war. While they were orginally about shipping (those who got letters were called "privateers"), several people have recently proposed granting "Cyber" Letters of Marque.

Comment: @Justaguy: So, either way you lose.  If the computer affects foreign commerce or communication, then you have violated federal law.  If you have managed to find and attack a computer that somehow does not, then state law is not pre-empted, and you have violated state law.

Comment: @NateEldredge Actually, it's not quite that simple. Your answer and my comment are right as far as they go, but neither goes far enough. Both are incomplete, for reasons I will explain in a bit.

Comment: @NateEldredge Our earlier answers did not go far enough b/c they did not deal with the issue of "extra-territoriality." As the name suggests, extra-territoriality arises when a government wants to apply its laws outside its borders. A you can easily imagine, extra-territoriality raises a host of practical and moral problems.

Comment: Because of these problems, many states (and the feds) have a "presumption against extra-territoriality." That presumption means that unless a statute explicitly and clearly states that it applies outside the borders, courts will presume that statutes only apply inside a government's borders. (IIRC around 20 states have clear presumptions against extra-territoriality; of the rest, ~ 1/2 clear do not, while it's unclear for the other 1/2.)

Comment: According to the most recent and definitive listing I could find, Colorado does not have an explicit presumption of extra-territoriality. Of course, this does not mean the CO courts would allow cases under CO law.

Comment: If you want to know more about extra-territoriality, William Dodge has two recent law review articles. The first covers the evolution of the doctrine -- especially recent developments -- in SCOTUS (https://harvardlawreview.org/print/vol-133/the-new-presumption-against-extraterritoriality/), while the second looks at the     doctrine in the state courts (https://lawreview.law.ucdavis.edu/issues/53/3/53-3_Dodge.pdf).

Comment: @Justaguy: It's assumed that the hacker is inside the US, so the US is applying the law to a person inside its borders for conduct they committed within its borders (i.e. sitting at their computer and typing certain things). Are you arguing that, because the *target* is outside the US, it would be extraterritorial?  That seems like a big stretch.

Comment: @NateEldredge No/Sorry. Given how slowly I'm responding, I should have made it clear that my response has to do with your claim that CO law could apply to someone in CO hacking a computer outside CO. My answer has nothing to do with the US applying the law.